# Subset in data table in R using list and specific column

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a list of columns to be subset and a specific column.

Data table has the following columns

```
columns in dataTable -> Date, a, b, c & d
colList <- c(a,b) -> this list comes from separate source
dataTable <- dataTable[,list(Date, mget(colList[colList %in% names(dataTabel)]))]
```

its returning a datatable with Date and rest in another column.

Any help on this.

Comment: Your use of pseudocode makes it impossible to be sure what you're asking, but there's `DT[, ..colList]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one-liner like this would do:

```
df[,c('Date','a','b','c','d')]
```

or

```
df[,list(Date,a,b,c,d)]
```

or

```
df[,.(Date,a,b,c,d)]
```